# Meaning behind converting LDA topics to "suitable" TF-IDF matrices

Tags: python, text-mining, tf-idf, lda

As a beginner in text mining, I am trying to replicate the analyses from [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3167132.3167166). Essentially, the authors extract LDA topics (1-4) from a document and then **"the topics extracted by LDA have been converted to suitable TF-IDF matrices that have been then used to predict..."** (not important what they predict, it's a bunch of regressions). Their definition of TF and IDF (section 4.2.5) seems common, though, my understanding is that the TF-IDF measures apply to a word in a document, not topics. Given that they have a case where they extract a single topic, I think it's impossible to use the probability of the topic in a document, as this will always be 1 (though correct me if I am wrong).

**So, what are the possible interpretations of converting LDA topics to "suitable TF-IDF" matrices?** (and how would one go about doing that using the below code?)

Would that mean converting each and every word in a document to its TF-IDF weight and then use in prediction? That does not seem plausible as with 1000+ documents, that'd be pretty high and almost certainly most of them would be useless.

**Minimally reproducible example**

(credit: [Jordan Barber](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/79360_850b2a69980c4488b1db95987a24867a.html#so-what-does-lda-actually-do))

```py
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from stop_words import get_stop_words
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from gensim import corpora, models
import gensim

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

# create English stop words list
en_stop = get_stop_words('en')

# Create p_stemmer of class PorterStemmer
p_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    
# create sample documents
doc_a = "Brocolli is good to eat. My brother likes to eat good brocolli, but not my mother."
doc_b = "My mother spends a lot of time driving my brother around to baseball practice."
doc_c = "Some health experts suggest that driving may cause increased tension and blood pressure."
doc_d = "I often feel pressure to perform well at school, but my mother never seems to drive my brother to do better."
doc_e = "Health professionals say that brocolli is good for your health." 

# compile sample documents into a list
doc_set = [doc_a, doc_b, doc_c, doc_d, doc_e]

# list for tokenized documents in loop
texts = []

# loop through document list
for i in doc_set:
    
    # clean and tokenize document string
    raw = i.lower()
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)

    # remove stop words from tokens
    stopped_tokens = [i for i in tokens if not i in en_stop]
    
    # stem tokens
    stemmed_tokens = [p_stemmer.stem(i) for i in stopped_tokens]
    
    # add tokens to list
    texts.append(stemmed_tokens)

# turn our tokenized documents into a id <-> term dictionary
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
    
# convert tokenized documents into a document-term matrix
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

# generate LDA model
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=2, id2word = dictionary, passes=20)
```